# "File not found" error when downloading File via DevExpress FileManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I use the `MVCFileManagerExtension` (DevExpress v14.2), an error "File Not Found" appeared when I tried to download a file.

This is my view code:

```
@model string

@Html.DevExpress().FileManager(settings =>
{
     settings.Name = "FileManager";

     settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "FileManager", Action = "FileManagerPartial" };
     ...
     settings.DownloadRouteValues = new { Controller = "FileManager", Action = "FileManagerPartialDownload" };

     settings.Settings.ThumbnailFolder = Url.Content("~/Content/FileManager/Thumbnails");

     settings.SettingsEditing.AllowDownload = true;
     ....

     settings.SettingsFileList.View = DevExpress.Web.FileListView.Thumbnails;
}).BindToFolder(Model).GetHtml()
```

Controller:

```
namespace NextERP.Controllers
{
    public class FileManagerController : Controller
    {
        public FileStreamResult FileManagerPartialDownload()
        {
            return FileManagerExtension.DownloadFiles(HomeControllerFileManagerSettings.CreateFileManagerDownloadSettings(), (string)HomeControllerFileManagerSettings.Model);
        }
    }

    public class HomeControllerFileManagerSettings
    {
       public const string Folder = @"~\";
       public static string Model { get { return Folder; } }

       public static DevExpress.Web.Mvc.FileManagerSettings CreateFileManagerDownloadSettings()
       {
         var settings = new DevExpress.Web.Mvc.FileManagerSettings();
         settings.SettingsEditing.AllowDownload = true;
         settings.Name = "FileManager";
         return settings;
       }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Other file manager settings looks to be valid, but root folder path declaration seems wrong:

```
public const string Folder = @"~\";
```

From `FileManagerExtension.DownloadFiles` [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcFileManagerExtension_DownloadFilestopic(kJUrUA)), `rootFolder` parameter contains value that specifies the root folder to which the FileManager extension is bound, hence you need to provide relative path for root folder, e.g.:

```
public const string Folder = @"~/Files";
```

Note that instead of using backslash like Windows file path, the relative path required by `DownloadFiles` uses slash (/) sign as folder name separator (i.e. application root folder marked as `~/`, same convention apply for `Url.Content` path).

During download request `FileManagerExtension` checks file availability based on server file path converted from given relative URL path, if the path is malformed or invalid in server side it will throw [FileNotFoundException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not work , this my new code Folder = @"~/Content/Manuals"

Answer (score 0):

Check the [ASPxUploadControl / MVC UploadControl - FAQ](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA18611) guide to resolve possible issues with file-based controls/extensions. Espessially, make sure that the corresponding routing exception is registered for handlers (p7):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
    ...
}
```